# ant built version of application fails to find dependent jar 

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

Trying to build a java application I am able to run the application successfully through Eclipse but I'm unable to run the jar file built by ant. I suspect my build.xml is to blame, I'm trying to get it right. Need help!

The mysql driver .jar file is in the lib/ directory in the project.

**error:**

```
$ java -jar dist/lib/MyProject.jar 
Loading Mysql JDBC driver...
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at com.test.bh1.bh.main(Unknown Source)
```

**bh.java**

```
package com.test.bh1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class bh {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println("Loading Mysql JDBC driver...");
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            msg ("Error instantiating mysql jdbc driver. E=" + e.getMessage());
            // bail. 
            return;
        }

        msg ("Successfully instantiated mysql jdbc driver. ");

        Connection con = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://servername:3306/databasename";
        String user = "username";
        String password = "password";

        try {            
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

            if (result.next()) {
                msg(result.getString(1));
            }

            con.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            msg(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private static void msg (String m) {
        System.out.println(m);
    }

}
```

**build.xml**

```
<project name="TestProj1" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Build File For This Project
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src"      location="src"/>
  <property name="build"    location="build"/>
  <property name="dist"     location="dist"/>
  <property name="user.name"    location="Brad Hein (CQA)"/>
  <property name="lib.dir"  location="lib/"/>
  <property name="mysql.jar"    location="mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar"/>
  <property name="appName.jar"  location="${dist}/lib/MyProject.jar"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

  <path id="build.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${mysql.jar}"/>
    <pathelement path="${appName.jar}"/>
  </path>


  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="false">
           <classpath refid="build.classpath"/>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy dependency libraries to the build path so they get packaged up in the distro jar file. -->
    <copy todir="${build}/lib">
         <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
             <include name="*.jar"/>
     </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>


  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution" >
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${appName.jar}" basedir="${build}">
    <!-- Creates a manifest file in the jar-->
        <manifest>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="./lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar"/>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.test.bh1.bh"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up" >
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you add mysql.jar to your classpath?

Comment: if I run it like this `$java -classpath ./lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar -jar dist/lib/MyProject.jar` it still exits with the same error

Comment: in your exception handling code, put e.printstacktrace() instead of getMessage().  it wont fix anything but you might have additional info on the cause.

Comment: Done. updated question with the stack trace.

Comment: I suspect you've got a typo in your jar file name. If you're on java-6 try this `$java -classpath ./lib/*.jar -jar dist/lib/MyProject.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this:

```
<attribute name="Class-Path" value="./lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar"/>
```

Says that the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` needs to be in a lib folder next to your `appName.jar`.  Not inside of it.   Try putting your lib folder with the mysql jar next to your `appName.jar` and running the application should confirm that this is the problem.

Comment: `lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` actually does exist next to the app jar thanks to an ant "copy" operation which is defined after the javac part of build.xml

Comment: @Brad - your buildfile copies the MySQL jar to build/lib, but you run the MyProject.jar in dist/lib.  When you do that, given your manifest classpath, java will expect the MySQL.jar to be in dist/lib/lib - i.e. under lib relative to the 'running' MyProject jar.

Comment: You were right. I copied the mysql.jar to dist/lib/lib and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
java -cp lib -jar dist/lib/MyProject.jar
```

Comment: Same result... `$ java -cp lib -jar dist/lib/MyProject.jar 
Loading Mysql JDBC driver...
Error instantiating mysql jdbc driver. E=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`